# For which $n$, $f:(x_1,\dots,x_n)\mapsto(x_1x_2^2,x_2x_3^2,\dots,x_{n-1}x_n^2,x_nx_1^2)$ is diffeomorphism?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology

I've had following problem to solve on exam and I did not know how to do it.

For which $n>2$, $f$ is diffeomorphism?
$$
f:\mathbb{R}_+^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_+^n
$$
$$
f:(x_1,\dots,x_n)\mapsto(x_1x_2^2,x_2x_3^2,\dots,x_{n-1}x_n^2,x_nx_1^2)
$$
Where $\mathbb{R}_+=(0,\infty)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Your function is the composition of

- Taking the logarithm at each coordinate
- Applying a certain linear transformation
- Taking the antilogarithm at each coordinate

So you have a series of mappings $\mathbb R_+^n\to \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R_+^n $. The first and last are clearly diffeomorphisms. How about the middle one?